# If with function i return a pointer created inside it,will the pointer's 4 bytes created in function be freed after it ends?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, scope

Any comments about the quality of my post are welcome,im new.

1)Will the 4 bytes of temp(pointer) be cleared after the function ends?

2)(Not from the code bellow)If i have pointer1 that points to address A and i copy address A to pointer2, how do i free the memory that pointer1(the 4 bytes as an int) takes and keep only the new pointer2?

(The code bellow)The code gets a number from user (lets say 4) and uses a function to make an array of size 4 with 1 in every slot.

```
int * Array_K_Size(int number)
{
    int *temp;

    temp = (int *) calloc(number,sizeof(int));

    for ( int i=0; i<number; i++)
        temp[i] = 1;

    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    int number,*ptr=NULL;

    printf("Give number: ");
    scanf("%i",&number);

    ptr = Array_K_Size(number);

    for ( int i=0; i<number; i++)
        printf("Position %3i of array is: %3i\n",i+1,ptr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function

```
int * Array_K_Size(int number)
{
    int *temp;

    temp = (int *) calloc(number,sizeof(int));

    for ( int i=0; i<number; i++)
        temp[i] = 1;

    return temp;
}
```

You dynamically allocated an array and a pointer to its first element is returned.

Its value is assigned to the pointer `ptr`

```
ptr = Array_K_Size(number);
```

That is the pointer `ptr` gets a copy of the value stored in the local pointer temp. The local variable temp will not be alive after exiting the function. Nevertheless the allocated dynamically memory is still alive outside the function.

To free the allocated memory you need just to call

```
free( ptr );
```

The scope of the pointer `temp` is the body of the function `Array_K_Size`.

The scope of the pointer `ptr` is the body of the function `main`.

From the C Standard (6.2.4 Storage durations of objects)

> 5 An object whose identifier is declared with no linkage and without
>   the storage-class specifier static has **automatic storage duration**,
>   as do some compound literals....

and

> 6 For such an object that does not have a variable length array type,
>   **its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is
>   associated until execution of that block ends in any way**

The both pointers `temp` and `ptr` have automatic storage duration but each is declared in each own block.

Comment: But free() will delete the pointer and the memory in the address,i want a way to delete only the 4 bytes that the pointer as an integer is taking in the memory(i NEED those 4 bytes hah)

Comment: @Jesepy I do not understand what you mean. free does not delete the pointer itself. It frees the memory pointed to by the pointer.

Comment: Pointer is an integer that has stored an address,i want to delete the integer/pointer and keep the memory in adress

Comment: @Jesepy Variables with automatic storage duration stop their life when the program control goes outside the scope where variables are declared. And pointers are not integers. So it is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Then i cant delete the pointer as an integer alone,but in the code does temp as an integer get deleted after the function ends?

Comment: @Jesepy Read one more my answer.

Comment: I see,its clear now thanks.(Stackoverflow:" dont post thanks in comments" eh)